# How to fix modal popup closing button's showing part on Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, modal-dialog

I successfully added "x" close button into modal popup. But when i click on it then shows only some part of the content. I'd want it to show full page of content not just upper part.

I've tried CSS code and this php code:

CSS:

```
.close-button {
  border: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap
}

.topright {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0
}
```

php:

```
<div id="surbma-yes-no-popup" class="uk-modal <?php echo 'surbma-yes-no-popup-' . $popupthemes; ?>">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <div class="uk-modal-header">
            <header style="background-color:#000;color:#fff;">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('surbma-yes-no-popup').style.display='none'" class="close-button topright" >&times;</span>
</header>       
            <h2><?php echo esc_attr_e( $options['popuptitle'] ); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-modal-content"><?php echo stripslashes( $options['popuptext'] ); ?></div>
        <div class="uk-modal-footer">
            <button id="button1" type="button" class="uk-button uk-button-large uk-button-<?php echo esc_attr_e( $options['popupbutton1style'] ); ?><?php if( $options['popupbuttonoptions'] != 'button-1-redirect' ) echo ' uk-modal-close'; ?>"><?php echo esc_attr_e( $options['popupbutton1text'] ); ?></button>
            <?php if( $popuphidebutton2 != 1 ) { ?>
                <button id="button2" type="button" class="uk-button uk-button-large uk-button-<?php echo esc_attr_e( $options['popupbutton2style'] ); ?><?php if( $options['popupbuttonoptions'] == 'button-1-redirect' ) echo ' uk-modal-close'; ?>"><?php echo esc_attr_e( $options['popupbutton2text'] ); ?></button>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is able to close the popup but it is only shows upper part of the content, not a full page. It is just like cut of upper page, i expect to show the full content after clicking on it. How to fix?

Comment: `onclick="document.getElementById('surbma-yes-no-popup').style.display='none'"`  should make all of the code in the "PHP" section of your code sample disappear. This is just a modal, right? Is there more HTML on the page that will be shown after the modal is closed?

Comment: yes just a modal and there are more html yes

Comment: And it's all there before the modal is launched, presumably? Does the page content vanish only after you close the modal?

Comment: yes all there before modal, yes the below content cutting and vanishes only after i click close button

Comment: There is not enough in your sample code to diagnose the issue. What you have here looks completely fine. Could you include HTML and CSS for the sections that are disappearing? This is not a PHP problem if it happens after user interaction, so it would be easier to interpret if you just include the source that gets sent to the browser.

Comment: It is surbma popup plugin.

Comment: I see the [Git repo](https://github.com/Surbma/surbma-yes-no-popup) but I'm not about to reverse engineer it to try solving the issue. Is the site on a publicly accessible server? It might be easiest to just take a look

Comment: @tshimkus ok here is: [link](https://vintagepornbay.com)